# Some problems in compiling cx_Oracle

Tags: python, c

I had a problem when I compile cx_Oracle5.1.2 using "python setup.py build". There are some build errors as follows:

```
Callback.c:49: error: ‘udt_Variable’ has no member named ‘data’
Callback.c:50: error: ‘udt_Variable’ has no member named ‘actualLength’
Callback.c:51: error: ‘udt_Variable’ has no member named ‘returnCode’
Callback.c:52: error: ‘udt_Variable’ has no member named ‘size’
Callback.c:52: error: ‘udt_VariableType’ has no member named ‘size’
Callback.c:53: error: ‘udt_Variable’ has no member named ‘bufferSize’
Callback.c:53: error: ‘udt_VariableType’ has no member named ‘size’
Callback.c:54: error: ‘udt_VariableType’ has no member named ‘isVariableLength’
Callback.c:55: error: ‘udt_Variable’ has no member named ‘bufferSize’
Callback.c: At top level:
Callback.c:65: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Callback.c:113: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Callback.c:154: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
Callback.c:176: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
```

What should I do?
Thanks.